# Почему нельзя посылать в Google, если сам движок SO так делает?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, google-it

Почему запрещается посылать в Google, но при этом сам SO это делает?

[Нахождение максимального отрицательного корня уравнения без заданного интервала](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931343/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0) (только пользователи с низкой репутацией увидят, либо незарегистрированные).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:** вопрос не о том, можно ли посылать в гугл или нет, а о том, что позиция по этому вопросу непоследовательная.

Comment: Очевидно же: чтобы гугл потом на эти ответы направлял трафик по этим вопросам.

Comment: Потому, что на самом деле цель отлична от помощи людям (включая цель -- обучить их). Цель -- накопление знаний в виде оцененных текстов.

Comment: Так еще с переводами трабла и в мобильной версии прикол.

Comment: Закинул [репорт на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323001/339911)

Comment: @jfs Текущий вопрос о неконсистентности позиции по поводу отправки в гугл, а не о том, что так делать не стоит. Следовательно, не дубликат вовсе.

Answer (score 8):

Если присмотреться к той ссылке, которую предлагает SO в предложении погуглить, то можно заметить, что в ней результаты поиска ограничены разделом вопросов текущего сайта, в данном случае ruSO:

> [image: ruSO]

Таким образом, это не то, чтобы призыв погуглить в целом, а вариант поиска возможных решений на сайте, но не средствами внутреннего поиска, а большим и серьёзным поисковым движком.

Comment: То есть послать в гугл, но не просто, а указав при этом правильную строку запроса, практически дающую ссылку с ответом на вопрос в топе результатов поиска - не возбраняется (а то же самое, но через lmgtfu - уже по-любому моветон)... или ограничение при этом поиска только на ru.stackoverfolw.com - это обязательное требование?

Comment: @Akina ограничение текущим сайтом - это ключевой момент, я думаю.

Comment: Вот и непонятно это... выдача поиска со временем по-любому сползёт - что на гугле, что здесь. А ведь порой показать, как именно надо было сформировать вопрос к поиску - даже более ценно для автора, чем ответ на частный вопрос. Хотя да, в таком случае можно обойтись и без ссылки, просто строкой поиска.

Comment: @Akina здесь всё же частная ситуация. Ссылка присутствует на странице вопроса, который был удалён в процессе модерации. Участникам с >10k этот вопрос виден и никаких ссылок в гугл нет. Более того, когда говорят "не отправляйте людей в гугл", имеют в виду, что не стоит этого делать при "живом" вопросе. Ведь если для существующего вопроса гугл находит эквивалент на текущем же сайте, то такой вопрос можно вполне себе предложить в качестве дубликата, т.е. использовать имеющийся функционал SO, а не просто скупую ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

Никаких противоречий тут нет. Основные проблемы отсылок в поисковики - следующие:

1. отправка в поиск обидна для задавшего вопрос;
2. страница, отправляющая в поиск, может попасться в результатах этого самого поиска, что мешает уже всем.

Остальные причины являются производными этих двух. Но легко видеть, что в приведённом вами случае (направление в поиск на удалённой странице) ни одна из этих проблем проблемой не является:

1. задавший вопрос видит текст удалённого вопроса вместо служебной страницы, а значит он не видит отсулки в гугл, кроме того мы уже его вынужденно обидели удалением вопроса - так что лишняя отсылка в гугл тут уже ничего не изменит;
2. страница закрыта от индексирования (ибо код 404 не индексируется), а значит в результатах поиска уже никому не попадётся.